# Replace values in a column, with certain values from another, ignoring any 'nan' entries

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
A  B   C   D  

2  a   1   F
4  b   2   G
6  b   3   nan
1  c   4   G
5  c   5   nan
7  d   6   H
```

I want to replace any values in column B, with the values in column D, while not doing anything for the 'nan' entries in column D.

Desired output:

```
A  B   C   D  

2  F   1   F
4  G   2   G
6  b   3   nan
1  G   4   G
5  c   5   nan
7  H   6   H
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few alternative solutions:

```
In [72]: df['B'] = df['D'].combine_first(df['B'])

In [73]: df
Out[73]:
   A  B  C    D
0  2  F  1    F
1  4  G  2    G
2  6  b  3  NaN
3  1  G  4    G
4  5  c  5  NaN
5  7  H  6    H
```

or:

```
df['B'] = df['D'].fillna(df['B'])
```

or:

```
df['B'] = df['D'].mask(df['D'].isnull(), df['B'])
```

or:

```
df['B'] = df['D'].where(df['D'].notnull(), df['B'])
```

or:

```
df['B'] = np.where(df['D'].notnull(), df['D'], df['B'])
```

Comment: Was just about to post the `fillna()` version ;-)

Comment: @NickilMaveli, i also just noticed that i forgot the most obvious one :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can mask the rows of interest using a boolean mask and pass this to `loc` so only those rows are overwritten:

```
In [3]:
df.loc[df['D'].notnull(), 'B'] = df['D']
df

Out[3]:
   A  B  C    D
0  2  F  1    F
1  4  G  2    G
2  6  b  3  NaN
3  1  G  4    G
4  5  c  5  NaN
5  7  H  6    H
```

See the docs on [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html#pandas.Series.notnull)